# AngularJS: Styling dragged item with drag and drop

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop

Basically all I want to do is have the dragged item have a decreased opacity so that it is slightly see through. My issue is that I can't seem to change the style of the item being dragged when it is initially started dragging.

```
<div class=" btn btn-droppable growBackground"
     ng-repeat="folder in Folders"
     data-drop="true"
     ng-model='Folders'
     jqyoui-droppable="{index: {{$index}},  onOver: 'moveFolderOnFolder($index)'}"
     data-jqyoui-options="{accept: '.folder'}">

        <div class="btn btn-draggable grow folder nospacing"
             data-drag="true"
             data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid', helper: 'clone'}"
             ng-model="Folders"
             <!-- IMPORTANT LINE HERE -->
             jqyoui-draggable="{index: {{$index}}, placeholder:true, animate:false, onDrag: 'storeDraggedFolderId(folder.Id)', onStart: 'addDraggingClass()', onStop: 'removeDraggingClass()' }">
            {{folder.Name}}
        </div>
```

The important bit of this code is in the second draggable div in the jqyoui options where i apply the folderopacity class through the onstop and onstart methods.

This code has the following effect -

[image: dragdrop]

The bottom block is the one being currently dragged. I want THIS one to have the opacity styling, but I can't find a way of doing it (at least initially anyway. If I do not remove the class when the dragging finished it will keep the opacity next time you drag it). I seem to have tried this with a bunch of the different attributes but yet no success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

if I understood you correctly you want to catch the "drag" event and accordingly use an ng-class to add/remove class right?

so you can either add a drag event that jqyoui-dragable is producing(I assume its angular-dragdrop):

http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#/
or you can just catch a mix of mousedown mouseup and mousemove events (prone to errors) and that with ng-class

the docs for the event are in the webpage.

you probably want to use onStart event catch it in the controller

> onStart- callback method to be invoked (has to be defined in a
> controller) when dragging starts

so in the docs it shows

```
<div jqyoui-draggable="{onStart:'startCallback(item)'}">
```

jsut add in the controller the callback:

```
    $scope.startCallback = function(){
    $scope.isDragged = true;
}
```

and in the box add

```
ng-class={'opacityClass':isDragged}
```

for the other option just check when mouse is down and not up and see that the mousemove has been triggered and if all those statuses occur update the ng-class.Dont see why but if you want Ill help out with that

naturally if the

Comment: Hi, if you look in my initial post I am using the onstart method to apply the class (sorry it's not very clear). The problem is that the class seems to only being applying to where the drag section initially appears on the screen, NOT the actual part being moved around by the mouse. If i don't remove the class when the dragging has finished, and i drag the same part again, it will have the opacity styling (but i obviously want to remove the styling when the dragging has stopped).

Comment: sorry missed the event. so you're saying you want the class to apply to where the item is dragged... so if I drag on the second box it gets the opacity and the first box class is removed? so essentially you want the class to be added according to your location? right?

Comment: Sorry, no, what I mean is that I want the div being moved around by my mouse to have a class applied while it is being dragged around, then it will lose the styling when it has stopped being dragged. The styling is being applied when being dragged, but not to the actual part being dragged. If you see my picture, the bottom item is being dragged, but the opacity class is not being applied. Instead it is applied to the objects starting position. I feel that onstart definitely should work but for some reason it isn't.

Comment: if you'll provide a jsfiddle or plunker ill help you solve this. but if you want the class to trigger on onDrag then you can do it, you probably need to look for more than one trigger... like add class on onDrag and remove it on onStop and you can probably do it in two ways... one is have several ng-class and onDrg or onStart pass the index or id of that box so you know which element to change. best if you provide a jsfiddle or something and ill help out ok?

Answer (score 0):

During dragging, the item dragged gets ui-draggable-dragging style appended to the class attribute.

Adding this to the css will do the trick:

```
.ui-draggable-dragging{
    opacity:0.3;
}
```